# Format table in word after copying from Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would like to copy text from Excel to a Word file, add a page break in between (between line 50 and 51) and format the table in the Word file adjust the width of the table to the page of the Word document.

I have tried the InsertBreak and SetWidth methods but somehow produce errors (either syntax or object not defined).

```
Sub Button1()    
Dim wd As Object    
Worksheets("1").Activate    
Range("C15:C73").Copy    
Set wd = CreateObject("word.application")    
wd.documents.Add    
wd.Visible = True    
wd.activedocument.Range.Pasteexceltable False, False, True    

Worksheets("2").Activate    

End Sub
```

The above is the code I  currently use which works but does not have the page break after line 50 included neither is the table correctly formatted, i.e. column is to wide.

Is somebody maybe so kind to help / point me in the right direction?

Comment: The site rule is one question per question. You have two. Please use the [edit] link below the question to narrow it to a single topic (I suggest the one mentioned in the title). Also include what you've tried that didn't work, the error(s) it generates and the line(s) that cause the error(s). We also need to know *exactly* what result you intend. "Neither is the table correctly formatted, i.e. Column is too wide" implies there's more than just the column width in question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and customize it to fit your needs:

```
Sub Button1()  

    ' Define object variables
    Dim wordObject As Object
    Dim wordDocument As Object
    Dim wordTable As Object
    Dim rangeToCopy As Range

    ' Define other variables
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rangeAddress As String
    Dim rowToInsertBreak As Integer

    ' >>>>>Customize
    sheetName = "Sheet1" ' Sheet name in Excel
    rangeAddress = "C15:C73" ' Range in Excel to copy from
    rowToInsertBreak = 25 ' (index starts at 0 and first row is the header

    ' Initiate word object
    Set wordObject = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    ' Add a new document
    Set wordDocument = wordObject.Documents.Add

    ' Make the window visible
    wordObject.Visible = True

    ' Define the range to copy
    Set rangeToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range(rangeAddress)

    ' Copy the range
    rangeToCopy.Copy

    ' Paste it into word
    wordDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False

    ' Reference the table we just pasted
    Set wordTable = wordDocument.Tables(1)

    ' Autofit the table
    wordTable.AutoFitBehavior 2 ' wdAutoFitWindow: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211923(v%3Doffice.11)

    ' Insert the page break after row
    wordTable.Rows(rowToInsertBreak).Range.InsertBreak Type:=7 ' wdPageBreak

    ' Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Here are some links you'd check:
How to properly copy and paste excel tables into word:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba

Note: It's often better to use word as a reference


How to deal with page breaks inside Word tables:
https://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/page-breaks-in-tables.html

Comment: Dear Ricardo, thank you so much! Your answer is extremely helpful and contains all the elements I Need in order to make file work. That is greatly appreciated!